# How to create shortcut with Win32 API and c language

Tags: c, winapi

I want to write a program to create a shortcut for a specific file by using win32 API in c. my IDE is visual studio 2010. 
I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776891(VS.85).aspx) page but its sample just not compile and return many errors.
I also find [this code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11467/How-to-create-short-cuts-link-files) but this always create a link with Target: "D:\Desktop\㩣睜湩潤獷湜瑯灥摡攮數" and I don't know why.
can someone tell me why the sample code of Microsoft is not working or the second one return something in Chinese shape language and also with wrong and constant location for any argument?
This is my code for MSDN sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "winnls.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR  *argv[])
{
    CreateLink(argv[1],__argv[2],argv[3]);
}

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLink* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 

            // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
            // for success.

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres; 
}
```

and the errors are:
    1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h' and
    2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Comment: The sample does not contain any `main` function.

Comment: The MSDN sample code works just fine. If it is not working for you then you are not using it correctly. As for the "Chinese" [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) you are seeing, it is likely caused by you passing an ANSI string where a Unicode string is expected due to an incorrect typecast. So please, stop showing other people's code and do show YOUR code instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for your comment, but unfortunately I'm not a c developer but I want to use win32 API to create links for my files. so I tried to edit the existing samples for my purpose. so can you tell me how can pass Unicode string as the argument in command line? I just followed the instruction of that code sample.

Comment: Calling `MultiByteToWideChar` unconditionally seems fishy to me. If you're already using wide chars (i.e. if you've defined `_UNICODE`), then what you have isn't encoded using the ACP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> CreateLink(argv[1],__argv[2],argv[3]);
> ```

This call looks weird.  You are using `argv[]` for two `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t *`) parameters, but are using `__argv[]` for an `LPCSTR` (`const char *`) parameter.  You should change the 2nd parameter to `LPCWSTR` to match the other parameters, and then use `argv[]` instead of `__argv[]`.

The `TCHAR`-based `IShellLink` works with `LP(C)WSTR` string parameters, and `LP(C)TSTR` is `LP(C)WSTR` when compiling for Unicode.  Which you are obviously doing, given that you are passing `TCHAR`-based `argv[]` values to `LPCWSTR` parameters, which will only compile if `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`.

`IPersistFile::Save()` takes only a Unicode string as input, regardless of what `TCHAR` maps to.  You are converting the `char*` value from `__argv[]` from ANSI to Unicode, so you may as well just get a Unicode string from `argv[]` to begin with, and omit the call to `MultiByteToWideChar()` altogether.

There is no good reason to mix ANSI and Unicode strings like this.  This is something the MSDN example is getting wrong.

And since your function parameters are working with Unicode strings, you should use the `IShellLinkW` interface directly instead of the `TCHAR`-based `IShellLink` interface.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shobjidl.h"
#include "objbase.h"
#include "objidl.h"
#include "shlguid.h"

HRESULT CreateLink(LPCWSTR lpszPathObj, LPCWSTR lpszPathLink, LPCWSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLinkW* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLinkW, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf; 

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(lpszPathLink, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 

        psl->Release(); 
    } 

    return hres; 
}

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 3)
        CreateLink(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man. but why I still get these errors:  C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h' and IntelliSense: cannot open source file "stdafx.h". I think these are not relevant to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio generates **stdafx.h** and **stdafx.cpp** when you are using **new project wizard**. If **Create empty project** checkmark is marked, it will not generate them. [These files are used to build a precompiled header file Projname.pch and a precompiled types file Stdafx.obj](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/h552b3ca.aspx)

For small projects you can eventually remove **#include "stdafx.h"**, but it would be better to create new project with **Create empty project** unmarked.